# For which values of $z$ is $\frac{1+zi}{1-zi}$ real negative?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let we have $\frac{1+zi}{1-zi}$ being $z\in{\mathbb{C}}$. For which values of $z$ is that fraction negative and real at the same time?

---

This is what I have done:$\space$

$\frac{1+zi}{1-zi}=\frac{1+zi}{1-zi}\cdot \frac{1+zi}{1+zi}=\frac{1-z^2}{1+z^2}+\frac{2z}{1+z^2}i$$\space$

As we want it to be real, $\frac{2z}{1+z^2}=0$ $\space$. So $z=0$.$\space$

And as we also want it to be negative, $1-z^2<0$ or $1+z^2=0$$\space$

But I don't know how to continue... Am I doing it ok? Or how can I solve my problem?

Comment: you have to use $z=x+iy$

Comment: I have tried it but I don't reach any solid conclusion... :| How can I do it?

Comment: write what you got at the separation of the fraction into its real and imaginary parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be real we need

$$\frac{1+zi}{1-zi}=\frac{1-\bar zi}{1+\bar zi} \iff 1+2i\Re(z)=1-2i\Re(z) \iff \Re(z)=0$$

that is by $z=iy$

$$\frac{1+zi}{1-zi}=\frac{1-y}{1+y}<0 \iff |y|>1$$